# How to turn off editing mode in UITableView when there are no more cells to delete?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios

I've tried putting this in various parts of my code, like at the end of commitEditingStyle method, but I can't get it to stop editing mode. Basically, I want to automatically exit editing mode when there are no more cells...

```
if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] ==0)
    {
        NSLog(@"this triggers, but doesn't stop editing..");
        self.tableView.editing = NO;
        [self.tableView endEditing:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

How about `[self setEditing:NO animated:YES]`? I suppose to self is an instance of UITableViewController.

Comment: its working fine: thanks ... [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];

Answer (score 12):

From the apple docs:

`Note: The data source should not call setEditing:animated: from within its implementation of tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:. If for some reason it must, it should invoke it after a delay by using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method.`

So, calling this within `commitEditingStyle` is not a great practice.

Comment: The old fashioned way, by screwing it up the first time!

Answer (score 5):

If is not just `[self setEditing:NO animated:YES]` ?

Answer (score 1):

After playing around with this, here are the things to know:
There are separate setEditing routines for the controller and for the tableView.  Make sure to use the one for the controller.
Also, it needs a delay as noted above.  For this, I used [Matt’s delay function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861).
As an added bonus, one can disable the Edit button when there are no items in your list.  The button becomes enabled again when an item is added. Code is in Swift5.

```
var someArray: [SomeStruct] = [] {
    didSet {
        if let btn = navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem {
            if someArray.count > 0 {
                btn.isEnabled = true
            } else {
                btn.isEnabled = false   // Needs to respond immediately - don't put in delay
                closeDownEditMode()
            }
        }
    }
}

func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}

func closeDownEditMode() {
    delay(0.1) { [weak self] in
        self?.setEditing(false, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [tooluser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15256040/2439941) the [docu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasource/1614871-tableview) states that `setEditing:animated:` should not be called from within `tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`. This is still the case in 2023.

However, a solution to make it work is inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54752481/2439941) to use `performBatchUpdates:completion:`.

Working example in iOS 15:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source:
        [_myData removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Update table view:
        [tableView performBatchUpdates:^{
            // Delete the row:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPaths]
                             withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            // Disable Edit mode if there is no more data (after deleting the last row):
            if ([self->_myData count] == 0) {
                [tableView setEditing:NO
                             animated:NO];
            }
        }];
   }
}
```