# dispatch_after - GCD in Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I've gone through the [iBook](https://web.archive.org/web/20140719155151/https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/BuildingCocoaApps.pdf) from Apple, and couldn't find any definition of it:

Can someone explain the structure of `dispatch_after`?

```
dispatch_after(<#when: dispatch_time_t#>, <#queue: dispatch_queue_t?#>, <#block: dispatch_block_t?#>)
```

Comment: Apple unpublished this book in 2018. [Latest archive I could find is from December 2017](https://web.archive.org/web/20171227051224/https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/index.html). Old links to the iBook now simply redirect to https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift.

Answer (score 767, accepted):

A clearer idea of the structure:

```
dispatch_after(when: dispatch_time_t, queue: dispatch_queue_t, block: dispatch_block_t?)
```

`dispatch_time_t` is a `UInt64`. The `dispatch_queue_t` is actually type aliased to an `NSObject`, but you should just use your familiar GCD methods to get queues. The block is a Swift closure. Specifically, `dispatch_block_t` is defined as `() -> Void`, which is equivalent to `() -> ()`.

Example usage:

```
let delayTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
dispatch_after(delayTime, dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    print("test")
}
```

**EDIT:**

I recommend using [@matt's really nice `delay` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861).

**EDIT 2:**

In Swift 3, there will be new wrappers for GCD. See here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0088-libdispatch-for-swift3.md

The original example would be written as follows in Swift 3:

```
let deadlineTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadlineTime) {
    print("test")
}
```

Note that you can write the `deadlineTime` declaration as `DispatchTime.now() + 1.0` and get the same result because the `+` operator is overridden as follows (similarly for `-`):

- `func +(time: DispatchTime, seconds: Double) -> DispatchTime`
- `func +(time: DispatchWalltime, interval: DispatchTimeInterval) -> DispatchWalltime`

This means that if you don't use the `DispatchTimeInterval` `enum` and just write a number, it is assumed that you are using seconds.

Comment: Tip: Because the block is the final parameter to the function, you can use Swift's "trailing closure" syntax for extra readability: `dispatch_after(1, dispatch_get_main_queue()) { println("test") }`

Comment: I think using the number `1` in `dispatch_after(1, ...` may cause a lot of confusion here. People will think it is a number of seconds, when it actually is **nano-second**. I suggest see @brindy 's answer on how to create this number properly.

Comment: Please change `1` to `dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(1 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))` because it leads to confusion. People could think that you don't need to create a dispatch_time_t in Swift

Comment: The Swift 3 version doesn't appear to be working. It complaints that `Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type DispatchTime and '_'` on the line `let delayTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(1.0)`

Comment: Rewriting it as `DispatchTime.now() + 1.0` seems to be the only way to make it work (no need for `.seconds`)

Comment: Thanks - updated the answer. The issue was actually that `DispatchTimeInterval.seconds` has an associated value of `Int`, so `let delayTime = DispatchTime.now + .seconds(1)` works.

Comment: As of Swift 3 beta 4, `after` is renamed to `asyncAfter`, and its parameter `when` is renamed to `deadline`.

Comment: `.seconds` needs a value of  `Int`, if you require a double value, use `.milliseconds` instead. e.g. `+ .milliseconds(1500)` is more swifty than `+ 1.5`

Answer (score 1114):

I use `dispatch_after` so often that I wrote a top-level utility function to make the syntax simpler:

```
func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```

And now you can talk like this:

```
delay(0.4) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Wow, a language where you can improve the language. What could be better?

---

#### Update for Swift 3, Xcode 8 Seed 6

Seems almost not worth bothering with, now that they've improved the calling syntax:

```
func delay(_ delay:Double, closure:@escaping ()->()) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
}
```

Comment: I just needed shortcut for the delay calculation, ended up with: `func delayInSec(delay: Double) -> dispatch_time_t { return dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))) }`

Comment: Would `delay(0.0) { /*stuff*/ }` (insert appropriate linebreaks) be a valid command if I wanted to do something on the main thread without any delay (such as modify the GUI)?

Comment: @Matt You tell me. You're looking at the code. What's the problem? Or if you're in doubt, call `dispatch_async` onto the main thread yourself. Again, what's the problem?

Comment: I love this usage. Similarly, you can do:
func onMainQueue(closure:()->()){
    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(closure)
}

Comment: It's not a bug and it has nothing to do with my `delay` function. And `->()` is the same thing as `->Void` isn't it? It's just a closure "feature". I run into this all the time with closures. Basically just don't write any one-line closures, because Swift will try to treat this as syntactic sugar for returning the result of that expression.

Comment: @matt Thanks for this code. It was working fine, but now I am getting the error, "Cannot convert the expression's type (FloatLiteralConvertible, () -> () -> $T3)' to type 'FloatLiteralConvertible' - Do you have any ideas why? Thanks ...

Comment: @agf119105 If you have just one line of code in the closure, add another line of code (e.g. `return`).

Comment: how could we weakify self here? is self strongly retained?

Comment: @GastonM Irrelevant. Passing a function has _of itself_ no memory management issues.

Comment: @matt - This is great, but forgive my ignorance: where do I put this code to make it a top-level function? Thanks.

Comment: @MikeTaverne At top level! (Of a swift file.) http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch01.html#_the_structure_of_a_swift_file

Comment: "A language where you can improve the language". I don't understand how defining a global function is improving the language, or why this isn't doable in C even. Maybe if you overload an operator ;) `1.0 ~~ { code...}`

Comment: You could make it even better with a 0 default value to the delay parameter. 
This way you can also write `delay {
//do stuff
}`
If you just need the execution to happen later

Comment: Not questioning the correctness of your answer—but isn't *"I use dispatch_after so often"* a code smell which would best be fought by **not** providing a convenience function?

Comment: @matt If this was called on global queue would it be less accurate? Or can it be on any queue and maintain the same accuracy and precision as when called on main queue? Thanks

Comment: @matt It would be great to use NSTimeInterval typealias for Double in this case.

Comment: NikolaiRuhe: No "code smell", but a nasal problem. @MikeG: Actually, it would be more accurate on a background queue. On a background queue, you have multiple threads and one can start _exactly_ when you ask. On the main queue, any task that is executing at the exact dispatch time will finish first.

Comment: You can simplify it to `let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay` in Swift 3 :) – Btw, I wonder what the function parameters should be called in accordance with https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/. Perhaps `delay(for:execute:)` ?

Comment: @MartinR Yes, thanks, I was just getting around to that. I don't understand what the migrator was thinking here... — I never liked `closure` but probably no one will ever see or use it, as they'll be using trailing closure syntax. And I like having no first parameter.

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Hmmmm...  I use a dispatch after .001 for `do on the next run loop` so as to let stuff get set up. In truth, that should be all handled by the `viewDidDisappear` and all those methods, but sometimes passing a block around so someone else can execute it turns into even more cumbersome code.

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure),` giver error that Dispatch Queue have no member `asyncAfter`

Comment: @rptwsthi Did you read what I said? Xcode 8, seed 4. You have not updated to Xcode 8 seed 4 (or seed 5).

Comment: How would you go about stopping the closure from executing. I am trying to do like a timer and every second a UILabel updates but if a user touches a certain button then the timer goes away.

Comment: @CodyWeaver Then use a timer. I've explained elsewhere how to write a cancelable timer using GCD.

Comment: In Swift 3, `@escaping` must be explicitly written in the code?

Answer (score 157):

**Swift 3+**

This is super-easy and elegant in Swift 3+:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.5) {
    // ...
}
```

**Older Answer:**

To expand on Cezary's answer, which will execute after 1 nanosecond, I had to do the following to execute after 4 and a half seconds.

```
let delay = 4.5 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay))
dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
```

Edit: I discovered that my original code was slightly wrong.  Implicit typing causes a compile error if you don't cast NSEC_PER_SEC to a Double.

If anyone can suggest a more optimal solution I'd be keen to hear it.

Comment: I get a compiler error for a deprecated API with `dispatch_get_current_queue()`.  I used `dispatch_get_main_queue()` instead.

Comment: @DavidL - thanks, `dispatch_get_main_queue()` is definitely what you should be using.  Will update.

Comment: i tried this in a playground with swift 3 and it doesn't work

Comment: @GAlexander Works for me.  Are you allowing the playground to execute indefinitely?

Comment: uhm, well no, i let run run for a couple of hours and still nothing printed.  here's what i used.  "import Dispatch
import Darwin
import CoreGraphics 'DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 4.5) {
  print(" got  here ")
} "

Comment: @GAlexander ah - you have to explicitly tell the Playground to allow indefinite execution.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/33536290/73479

Comment: You should move your Swift 3+ code to the top of the answer. Or even delete the old code.

Answer (score 84):

[matt's syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24034544/dispatch-after-gcd-in-swift/24318861#24318861) is very nice and if you need to invalidate the block, you may want to use this :

```
typealias dispatch_cancelable_closure = (cancel : Bool) -> Void

func delay(time:NSTimeInterval, closure:()->Void) ->  dispatch_cancelable_closure? {

    func dispatch_later(clsr:()->Void) {
        dispatch_after(
            dispatch_time(
                DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
                Int64(time * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
            ),
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), clsr)
    }

    var closure:dispatch_block_t? = closure
    var cancelableClosure:dispatch_cancelable_closure?

    let delayedClosure:dispatch_cancelable_closure = { cancel in
        if closure != nil {
            if (cancel == false) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure!);
            }
        }
        closure = nil
        cancelableClosure = nil
    }

    cancelableClosure = delayedClosure

    dispatch_later {
        if let delayedClosure = cancelableClosure {
            delayedClosure(cancel: false)
        }
    }

    return cancelableClosure;
}

func cancel_delay(closure:dispatch_cancelable_closure?) {

    if closure != nil {
        closure!(cancel: true)
    }
}
```

Use as follow

```
let retVal = delay(2.0) {
    println("Later")
}
delay(1.0) {
    cancel_delay(retVal)
}
```

[credits](http://sebastienthiebaud.us/blog/ios/gcd/block/2014/04/09/diggint-into-gcd-1-cancel-dispatch-after.html)

*Link above seems to be down. [Original Objc code from Github](https://github.com/SebastienThiebaud/dispatch_cancelable_block)*

Comment: The one performance feature that has performSelector:afterDelay is ability to cancel it. Only this solution covers the problem. Thanks

Comment: @HotJard Note that `performSelector:afterDelay:` is now available in Swift 2, so you can cancel it.

Comment: @matt but it's available only for NSObject, isn't it?

Comment: @HotJard Sure but that's better than not having it at all. I see no issue there. However, just as with this answer, I had already compensated for its loss by writing a GCD-based cancelable timer (using a `dispatch_source_t`, because that's something you can cancel).

Comment: how would I make this so that I can call  `delay(1.0) {
    cancel_delay(retVal)
}` from another method such as didSelectRowAtIndexPath...?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've been using this up to Swift 2.3. Swift 3.0 compiler is complaining now, would be great if you updated your answer!

Comment: I don't know this has to be so complicated as of Swift 5.x

Answer (score 32):

**Simplest solution in Swift 3.0 & Swift 4.0 & Swift 5.0**

```
func delayWithSeconds(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + seconds) { 
        completion()
    }
}
```

Usage

```
delayWithSeconds(1) {
   //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 24):

Apple has a *dispatch_after snippet* for **Objective-C**:

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(<#delayInSeconds#> * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
});
```

Here is the same snippet ported to **Swift** 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + <#delayInSeconds#>) {
  <#code to be executed after a specified delay#>
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Another way is to extend Double like this:

```
extension Double {
   var dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t {
       get {
           return dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,Int64(self * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
       }
   }
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
dispatch_after(Double(2.0).dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
            self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    })
```

I like matt's delay function but just out of preference I'd rather limit passing closures around.

Answer (score 9):

**In Swift 3.0**

**Dispatch queues**

```
  DispatchQueue(label: "test").async {
        //long running Background Task
        for obj in 0...1000 {
            print("async \(obj)")
        }

        // UI update in main queue
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { 
            print("UI update on main queue")
        })

    }

    DispatchQueue(label: "m").sync {
        //long running Background Task
        for obj in 0...1000 {
            print("sync \(obj)")
        }

        // UI update in main queue
        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: {
            print("UI update on main queue")
        })
    }
```

**Dispatch after 5 seconds**

```
    DispatchQueue.main.after(when: DispatchTime.now() + 5) {
        print("Dispatch after 5 sec")
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

1) Add this method as a part of UIViewController Extension.

```
extension UIViewController{
func runAfterDelay(delay: NSTimeInterval, block: dispatch_block_t) {
        let time = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
        dispatch_after(time, dispatch_get_main_queue(), block)
    }
}
```

Call this method on VC:

```
    self.runAfterDelay(5.0, block: {
     //Add code to this block
        print("run After Delay Success")
    })
```

2)

```
performSelector("yourMethod Name", withObject: nil, afterDelay: 1)
```

3)

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2), dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> () in
    //Code Here
})
```

//Compact Form

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 2), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    //Code here
 }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Although not the original question by the OP, certain `NSTimer` related questions have been marked as duplicates of this question, so it is worth including an `NSTimer` answer here.

## `NSTimer` vs `dispatch_after`

- `NSTimer` is more high level while `dispatch_after` is more low level.
- `NSTimer` is easier to cancel. Canceling `dispatch_after` requires writing [more code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25120393/3681880).

## Delaying a task with `NSTimer`

Create an `NSTimer` instance.

```
var timer = NSTimer()
```

Start the timer with the delay that you need.

```
// invalidate the timer if there is any chance that it could have been called before
timer.invalidate()
// delay of 2 seconds
timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(delayedAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
```

Add a function to be called after the delay (using whatever name you used for the `selector` parameter above).

```
func delayedAction() {
    print("Delayed action has now started."
}
```

## Notes

- If you need to cancel the action before it happens, simply call `timer.invalidate()`.
- For a repeated action use `repeats: true`.
- If you have a one time event with no need to cancel then there is no need to create the `timer` instance variable. The following will suffice:

  ```
  NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(2.0, target: self, selector: #selector(delayedAction), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
  ```
- See my fuller answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34088708/3681880).

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 3.0  version**

Following closure function execute some task after delay on main thread.

```
func performAfterDelay(delay : Double, onCompletion: @escaping() -> Void){

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay, execute: {
       onCompletion()
    })
}
```

Call this function like:

```
performAfterDelay(delay: 4.0) {
  print("test")
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 5, use in the below:

```
 DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2, execute: closure) 

// time gap, specify unit is second
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(2)) {
            Singleton.shared().printDate()
        }
// default time gap is second, you can reduce it
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.2) {
          // just do it!
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**For multiple functions use this. This is very helpful to use animations or Activity loader for static functions or any UI Update.**

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.9) {
            // Call your function 1
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                // Call your function 2
            }
        }
```

**For example - Use a animation before a tableView reloads. Or any other UI update after the animation.**

```
*// Start your amination* 
self.startAnimation()
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.9) {
                *// The animation will execute depending on the delay time*
                self.stopAnimation()
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                    *// Now update your view*
                     self.fetchData()
                     self.updateUI()
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me.

Swift 3:

```
let time1 = 8.23
let time2 = 3.42

// Delay 2 seconds

DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2.0) {
    print("Sum of times: \(time1 + time2)")
}
```

Objective-C:

```
CGFloat time1 = 3.49;
CGFloat time2 = 8.13;

// Delay 2 seconds

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    CGFloat newTime = time1 + time2;
    NSLog(@"New time: %f", newTime);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3 & 4:**

You can create a extension on DispatchQueue and add function delay which uses DispatchQueue asyncAfter function internally

```
extension DispatchQueue {
    static func delay(_ delay: DispatchTimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> ()) {
        let timeInterval = DispatchTime.now() + delay
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: timeInterval, execute: closure)
    }
}
```

use:

```
DispatchQueue.delay(.seconds(1)) {
    print("This is after delay")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another helper to delay your code that is **100% Swift in usage** and optionally allows for **choosing a different thread** to run your delayed code from:

```
public func delay(bySeconds seconds: Double, dispatchLevel: DispatchLevel = .main, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + seconds
    dispatchLevel.dispatchQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime, execute: closure)
}

public enum DispatchLevel {
    case main, userInteractive, userInitiated, utility, background
    var dispatchQueue: DispatchQueue {
        switch self {
        case .main:                 return DispatchQueue.main
        case .userInteractive:      return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)
        case .userInitiated:        return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
        case .utility:              return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility)
        case .background:           return DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you simply **delay your code on the Main thread** like this:

```
delay(bySeconds: 1.5) { 
    // delayed code
}
```

If you want to **delay your code to a different thread**:

```
delay(bySeconds: 1.5, dispatchLevel: .background) { 
    // delayed code that will run on background thread
}
```

---

If you prefer a **Framework** that also has some more handy features then checkout **[HandySwift](https://github.com/Flinesoft/HandySwift)**. You can add it to your project **via Carthage** then use it exactly like in the examples above, e.g.:

```
import HandySwift    

delay(bySeconds: 1.5) { 
    // delayed code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**I always prefer to use extension instead of free functions.**

*Swift 4*

```
public extension DispatchQueue {

  private class func delay(delay: TimeInterval, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let when = DispatchTime.now() + delay
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: when, execute: closure)
  }

  class func performAction(after seconds: TimeInterval, callBack: @escaping (() -> Void) ) {
    DispatchQueue.delay(delay: seconds) {
      callBack()
    }
  }

}
```

Use as follow.

```
DispatchQueue.performAction(after: 0.3) {
  // Code Here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Delaying GCD call using asyncAfter in swift**

```
let delayQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.theappmaker.in", qos: .userInitiated)
let additionalTime: DispatchTimeInterval = .seconds(2)
```

**We can delay as **microseconds**,**milliseconds**,**nanoseconds**

```
delayQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.60) {
    print(Date())
}

delayQueue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + additionalTime) {
    print(Date())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // ...
});
```

The `dispatch_after(_:_:_:)` function takes three parameters:

> a delay
>   a dispatch queue
>   a block or closure

The `dispatch_after(_:_:_:)` function invokes the block or closure on the dispatch queue that is passed to the function after a given delay. Note that the delay is created using the `dispatch_time(_:_:)` function. Remember this because we also use this function in Swift.

I recommend to go through the tutorial [Raywenderlich Dispatch tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

In **Swift 4**

Use this snippet:

```
    let delayInSec = 1.0
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delayInSec) {
       // code here
       print("It works")
    }
```

Comment: This is already in other answers (brindy's, for example, or Rahul's)... same syntax...

Answer (score 1):

Here is synchronous version of asyncAfter in Swift:

```
let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore.init(value: 0)
DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(DispatchQueue.global()))
    semaphore.signal()
}

semaphore.wait()
```

Along with asynchronous one:

```
let deadline = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: deadline) {
    dispatchPrecondition(condition: .onQueue(DispatchQueue.global()))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to perform some UI related task after 2.0 seconds.

```
            let delay = 2.0
            let delayInNanoSeconds = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
            let mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

            dispatch_after(delayInNanoSeconds, mainQueue, {

                print("Some UI related task after delay")
            })
```

**Swift 3.0  version**

Following closure function execute some task after delay on main thread.

```
func performAfterDelay(delay : Double, onCompletion: @escaping() -> Void){

    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delay, execute: {
       onCompletion()
    })
}
```

Call this function like:

```
performAfterDelay(delay: 4.0) {
  print("test")
}
```

Comment: This is almost identical to the previous answers

Comment: It seems that this answer was done early 2016, and is older than at least other 6 answers..

Answer (score 0):

Now more than syntactic sugar for asynchronous dispatches in Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) in Swift.

add Podfile

```
pod 'AsyncSwift'
```

Then,you can use it like this.

```
let seconds = 3.0
Async.main(after: seconds) {
print("Is called after 3 seconds")
}.background(after: 6.0) {
print("At least 3.0 seconds after previous block, and 6.0 after Async code is called")
}
```

Comment: Apple has given us all needed to use GCD in few lines. Why to bother with pods, workspace and so on?
Simply read docs about @escaping and capturing. it is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4 has a pretty short way of doing this:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2, repeats: false) { (timer) in
    // Your stuff here
    print("hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Preserve the `current queue`!

Besides good answers of this question, you may also consider preserving the current queue to prevent unnecessarily main queue operations (for example when you are trying to delay some async operations).

```
func after(_ delay: TimeInterval,
           perform block: @escaping ()->(),
           on queue: DispatchQueue = OperationQueue.current?.underlyingQueue ?? .main) { // So this `queue` preserves the current queue and defaulted to the `main`. Also the caller can pass in the desired queue explicitly
    queue.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay, execute: block)
}
```

#### Usage:

```
after(3) {
    // will be executed on the caller's queue
    print(Date())
}
```

Answer (score -1):

To execute a funtion or code after a delay use the next method

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 'secondsOfDelay') {
        your code here...
    }
```

**Example** - In this example the funtion `getShowMovies` will be executed after 1 second

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.getShowMovies()
    }
```